# How to Create New Column Based on Existing Column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

Hi. Currently, `para_str` is a novel broken into paragraph form. I'm trying to see if each row of `para_str` contains dialogue in it by looking for sentences that start and end with quotes. If they do have quotes, I want the text_type column of that row to display "Dialogue" and if not then "Narrative". How can I do this?

I tried this, but it does not seem to work:

```
dfp.loc[dfp['para_str'].str.contains('"\w+"', regex=True), 'text_type'] = "Dialogue"
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy column:

```
df['Dialogue'] = df['para_str']
```

Apply REGEX:

```
import re

def getQuotes(string):
    return re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', string)

df2 = df['Dialogue'].apply(lambda x: getQuotes(x))
df['Dialogue'] = df2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use df.loc, you just need to make a Dialogue mask, and then you can Change it to dialogue/narrative

````
Dialogue = df['para_str'].str.contains('"', na=True)
df.loc[Dialogue, 'text_type'] = "Dialogue"
df.replace(to_replace = "None", value = "Narrative")```
````